# A simpler and self-contained number picker?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, phonegap, numberpicker

In searching for number picker javascript code for a PhoneGap app I'm making, I came across this: https://plugins.jquery.com/dpNumberPicker/

It does what I need very well but looks overly complicated. I've searched out lots of code and this one does what I need the best. I'm wondering if there's a much simpler way to achieve a cross-platform (Android and iOS) mobile-ready (tappable) number picker? I need something that lets me make a stylable button with a - sign, stylable box where the number appears, and a following stylable + sign, and both buttons can be styled independently or both share the same style code, as well as the + and - being stylable as well.

In short, this:
[-][ 0 ][+]

Is there anything simpler (as in far less lines of code) that does what the DP Number Picker does the way it does it? This number picker is handsome code but it came out in 2014. I was hoping there was a neater and shorter way to achieve this.

If there's an answer to this, is there a way to make the buttons only appear and the number box be stylable when you tap on the number input box, and then the buttons disappear and number box goes back to its default untapped style after a pre-defined number of seconds of not tapping?

`Going from this:
     0 
To this:
[-][ 0 ][+]
And back again after you stop tapping:
     5`

Comment: AFAIK, PhoneGap does support `<input type="number">`, but it may not have the appearance you want, and you said you already found a solution, but want the code to be shorter. If you want your own custom coded solution, you should probably show the effort of trying to code a custom coded solution yourself first.

Comment: I’m not asking for someone to code it for me. I’m just asking if there’s a simpler way so I can try to figure it out myself. I’m learning JavaScript and want to know if there’s any point to me trying to write this code simpler or if I should just use the code I found. If you don’t want to answer my question, maybe try just not answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to answer your questions (as you commented that you only wanted to know if there was any point in trying to code this yourself):

> Is there anything simpler (as in far less lines of code) that does what the DP Number Picker does the way it does it? This number picker is handsome code but it came out in 2014. I was hoping there was a neater and shorter way to achieve this.

Unless you can use `<input type="number">`, you could code a custom solution yourself. A custom coded solution is almost always likely to be shorter than a general solution made by others, since you only code the functionality you specifically need. What you are asking should not be too hard to code, and probably a good exercise when learning JavaScript.

> If there's an answer to this, is there a way to make the buttons only appear and the number box be stylable when you tap on the number input box, and then the buttons disappear and number box goes back to its default untapped style after a pre-defined number of seconds of not tapping?

Yes, you can make appearence and styling change as a result of user interaction by using event listeners on the input box and the buttons. You could also make the appearance change back to default after a set time of inactivity by [debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Beautiful response! I appreciate it. I’ll dig deeper and see what I can figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm in the middle of cobbling one together right now, feel free to use my fumbling attempt and make it yours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Making a number picker. Hatchnet 2019</title>
<style>

.numberpkr {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}

.numbertext {
    position: absolute;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:18px;
    height:18px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    text-align:right;
    left:22px;
    top:0;
}

.plusminus{
    position: absolute;
    padding:2px;
    line-height:14px;
    height:14px;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    width:16px;
}
.plusname:hover{
    background:green;
    color:white;
}
.plusname {
    color:green;
    right:-44px;
    top:0;
}
.minusname:hover{
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
.minusname {
    color:red;
    left:0px;
    top:0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

Some text
<div id="picker"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// call on your div
numberPicker("picker");

function numberPicker($id)
{
    // the parent div
    var numberpkr = document.createElement('div'); 
    // the child divs
    var plusDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var minusDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var numberText = document.createElement('div');

    w = document.getElementById($id); // where the picker will go

    numberpkr.className="numberpkr";

    // the plus
    plusDiv.className="plusname plusminus";
    plusDiv.innerHTML = "+";
    plusDiv.onclick = function(){pkrclicked($id, "+");};

    // the minus
    minusDiv.className="minusname plusminus";
    minusDiv.innerHTML = "-";
    minusDiv.onclick = function(){pkrclicked($id, "-");};

    // the acutal number
    numberText.className="numbertext";
    numberText.innerHTML = "0";
    numberText.id = $id + "_1";

    numberpkr.appendChild(minusDiv);
    numberpkr.appendChild(plusDiv);
    numberpkr.appendChild(numberText);
    w.appendChild(numberpkr);
}
function pkrclicked($id, $d)
{
    if($d == "+")
    {
        $n = document.getElementById($id + "_1").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById($id + "_1").innerHTML = parseInt($n) + 1;
    }
    if($d == "-")
    {
        $n = document.getElementById($id + "_1").innerHTML;
        if(parseInt($n) > 0)
        {
            document.getElementById($id + "_1").innerHTML = parseInt($n) - 1;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```